# Is there any way to make the flutter opening be faster?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to build the app in release mode on Play Store, but when i start rollup my app, the google give me some advice, one of performance and i wanna know how can i make better the opening app, my app took 6744 ms to launch for the first time[image: and here is the image which says my performance]

I need know how can i better this... I've tried change somethings of my init, but now i have just this in my app initializing

```
void main() {
  final Map<String, dynamic> env = Environment.getConfig();
  RestClient.baseUrl = env['apiV4'];
  initializeDateFormatting('pt_BR', null).then((_) => runApp(MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      blocs: Blocs.getBlocs(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Vendor',
        theme: LjTheme.getTheme(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: Routes.getRoutes(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what is Environment.getConfig() doing? any async task should be completely avoided before running your app. If you TRULY need to make an async call, show a splash screen with loading indicator.

Comment: Environment.getConfig() is a function to get the environment vars of staging or production, is just one function without async:
```class Environment {
  static Map<String, dynamic> getConfig() {
    if (Foundation.kReleaseMode) {
      return ProdEnvironment.getProdConfig();
    }

    return StagingEnvironment.getStagingConfig();
  }
}```

Comment: And the getProdConfig or getStagingConfig is:
```class ProdEnvironment {
  static getProdConfig() {
    return {
      'apiV4': 'https://api.lejour.com.br/api/v4',
      'payment': 'https://api.lejour.com.br/lejour-payment/api/v1',
    };
  }
}```

Comment: but is being called from a server? from firebase? is even worst if that's the case and you're not doing it async... that blocks your thread and avoid the app startup until that finishes

Comment: It's been called from my own code, i have a file with my configs

Comment: Did you print out how long that task takes? Because you're blocking "runApp" to start until that's done.

Comment: i'll see how long that task takes, and i return you... wait a minute

Comment: I printed date time milliseconds since epoch when i started my main and the output is: 56 ms to build the app... i don't understand why in play console took so much time

Comment: Here a piece of my code: ```void main() {
  print(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch);
  final Map<String, dynamic> env = Environment.getConfig();
  Heading.textStyle = MyApp.theme.textTheme.title.copyWith();
  RestClient.baseUrl = env['apiV4'];
  initializeDateFormatting('pt_BR', null).then((_) {
    print(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch);
    return runApp(MyApp());
  });
}```

Comment: and you know the result of that?

Comment: so, opened in 56 milliseconds, in my emulator.... and opened normally

Comment: when you click on "view issue" does it let you know which device and which process is taking so long? Have you tried with your phone in airplane mode?

Comment: I see in which device is, was in Motorola Z and P8 Lite (Huawei), in another devices works fine